# Dynamically adding href target and open that in new tab

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, href, servercontrols

My Code is:

```
 <a href='<%# Eval("websitename")%>' runat="server" target="_blank">
 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("websitename")%>'></asp:Label>
 </a>
```

I will bind website name from code behind, when i click that it searches that website inside my local host.

if that website name is "www.stackoverflow.com"
it open like "localhost:1234/www.stackoverflow.com

How to redirect to www.stackoverflow.com.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should add http:// at the beginning of your "websitename". This tells your browser to use http protocol instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if websitename starts with `http://` and if not, add it.

Or if websitename  never starts with `http://`, just do

```
<a href='<%# "http://" + Eval("websitename")%>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `http://` to the beginning of the address:

```
 <a href='http://<%# Eval("websitename")%>' runat="server" target="_blank">
       <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("websitename")%>'></asp:Label>
 </a>
```